# Validating 1 of 2 fields with Code Igniter Forms

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

I have a problem I'm trying to resolve in a bit of a cleaner way.  Basically what is happening is I have a form in which I have 2 fields and one or the other needs to be present for the form to be valid.  My problem is that if I mark the two fields as required, they will be required for the entire form entry process.

```
if ($this->input->post('field1'))
{
    make field1 required
}
else if ($this->input->post('field2'))
{
    make field2 required
}
else
{
    make field1 && field2 required
}
```

The problem lies with the else... If I make them both required; the first time it looks for errors it checks for both fields to be populated and if field1 is populated, field2 will show as being required when it really shouldn't and the error message will not go away after checking again.

The other option is leaving field1 and 2 not required but that would mean that if they enter the correct info but leave both those fields blank it will submit.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

** Notes: I believe I have resolved the issue, by setting both field1 + field2 to required on load, they update based on the users input and the click event on the submit button.

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest and the easiest way to validate form in codeigniter is by using their form [validation library](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html)

```
First you have to manually load or auto load your library

$this->load->library('form_validation'); or $autoload['libraries']= array('form_validation');

You have to set rules for each field like

$this->form_validation('field_name','Field Label','required');
```

Their Manual is really worth reading. I am also currently developing a application with codeigniter and its really fun and easy

Comment: Yeah I just started with it and I'm having a blast.  I managed to figure out my problem.  I'm not sure why, but it might have been my local environment the errors were not being read dynamically.  I set both field 1 + 2 to be required and then if the users updates the form the fields change to being not required based on the user's input and updates the error messages accordingly!   CHeers for the help.